# django models-design: "ptr field is required"

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm using Python 3.6+PostgreSQL 10+latest Django and DjangoRestFRamework. I have the following models, in which several models inherit from a class which is the ForeignKey (One-to-Many) of another class.

```
class Voteable(models.Model):
      Voteable_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True);

class base(Voteable):
    class Meta:
        abstract = False

class traslated_info(models.Model):
    info_about=models.ForeignKey(base)
    info_body=models.TextField()
    info_language=models.CharField(max_length=2)

class A(base):
    A_id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    A_field=models.TextField()

class B(base):
    B_id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    B_field=models.TextField()
    B_belongs_to=models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(base):
    C_id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    C_field=models.TextField()
    C_belongs_to=models.ForeignKey(A)
    C_belongs_to=models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Whenever I try saving an object A (via curl), django says that base_ptr is required. I don't know how to model this situation. The end user is not expected to create item base and then item A, B or C. I tried class base as abstract, but an abstract class can't be ForeignKey. I want to automatically create a base class whenever a class A is created.

I think I have two options: A) Remove the ForeignKey and store the language-specific info fields as HStoreField. This makes the code somewhate dependent on Postgree. B) Create some sort of routine that automatically creates parent **base item** whenever a child **A item** is created (preserving the one to one relationship).

What do you recommend? Is there some django easy option I'm missing to make option B? I have not found this. Thank you.

Comment: Models are not really OOP classes. Models are database relations. Inheritance (unless you are using AbstractModel) is rarely the right thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Having an autofield as primary_key in the models A, B or C causes this error, as creating a child model doesn't cascade-create parents.
I found two workarounds:

- Change autofield option primary_key to false and add
  SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS=['fields.E100']
- Overriding Viewset ***create*** method:

@transaction.atomic

```
def create(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    request.data['base_ptr'] = base.objects.create(user=request.user,created_date=datetime.utcnow()).pk
    return super(viewsets.ModelViewSet,self).create(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

I will stick with the second, I'm quite sure more issues will arise.

Answer (score 0):

Make your serializer as below, you dont need to create base classes explicitly, it will be created automatically.

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        read_only_fields = ('base_ptr',)
        fields = '__all__'
```